# Draw Longest Straight Line in Contours OpenCv

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV and Python. I am trying to draw the longest straight line inside a contours.

I have a contour named `cnt`. The image is binary, the inside of the contours is white and the outside is black. I would like to draw the longest straight line inside the white contours. I found how to draw lines using `cv2.lines` but I didn't find how to draw the longest one. Do you have any ideas? The best would be to be able to generate all the straight lines inside the contours then to find the longest one.

```
img_copy = cv2.dilate(copy.deepcopy(img),np.ones((2,2),np.uint8),iterations = 2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(copy.deepcopy(img_copy),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt = contours[max_index]
```

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same exact question, but improve the first one

Comment: I forgot to add that the lines were straight.

Comment: _lines_ are always straight, or they would be a _curve_. You can edit your previous question, no need to make a new one